# AS3 - Need to save the mp3 file after cutting from beginning and end

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mp3, trim

I've to develop a mp3 audio cutter(similar to mp3cut.net), in that user can cut the audio from beginning or from end.

I'm able to open and save the .mp3 file on local system without modifying the bytearray. But need to save the file after trimming. I tried to extract the bytearray using sound.extract() but after saving the bytearray .mp3 file is not playing.

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you encoding the bytearray or are you saving the bytearray to file?

You need encode the bytearray

try with this:

https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy

Comment: Thanks Esdebon, I've not found anything related to converting a raw bytearray to mp3 format in provided link. I've tried the shine library also but it only converts riff wav files to mp3 format. I need to convert a mp3 raw bytearray to mp3 format.

Comment: I've to save the bytearray on local system after encoding to mp3. Below link only convert the wav bytearray to mp3:https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy